# jq filtering sub-array values with main values of an object

Tags: json, jq

I am having an issue figuring out what filters and methods I need to use in jq to transform my json data into what I am looking for. Every combination I have tried has ended up either not working at all, or iterating for each value, for each sub-arrary, for each object.

I have spent too long on this and am not making any more progress. Need someone to put another set of eyes on it. I am sure it is something more simple than I am making it out to be, but I am just unable to figure it out!

Here is the json data I am working with:

```
[
    {
        "location": "locationa",
        "services": [
            {
                "name": "serviceA",
                "version": "5.2.0.2",
                "updatedAt": "2018-04-17"
            },
            {
                "name": "serviceB",
                "version": "4.19.0.5",
                "updatedAt": "2018-04-17"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "location": "locationb",
        "services": [
            {
                "name": "serviceA",
                "version": "5.2.0.2",
                "updatedAt": "2018-04-17"
            },
            {
                "name": "serviceB",
                "version": "4.19.0.5",
                "updatedAt": "2018-04-17"
            },
            {
                "name": "serviceC",
                "version": "1.0.0.1",
                "updatedAt": "2018-04-17"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

And this is the format I am attempting to get out:

```
locationa serviceA 5.2.0.2
locationa serviceB 4.19.0.5
locationb serviceA 5.2.0.2
locationb serviceB 4.19.0.5
locationb serviceC 1.0.0.1
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Stack Overflow is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiastic programmers. Add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Answer (score 1):

you can concatenate strings using `+` operator:

```
jq -r '.[]|.location+" "+(.services[]|.name+" "+.version)' file
locationa serviceA 5.2.0.2
locationa serviceB 4.19.0.5
locationb serviceA 5.2.0.2
locationb serviceB 4.19.0.5
locationb serviceC 1.0.0.1
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally when trying to output csv/tsv, you would want to generate arrays of the rows to output then pass to the `@csv` or `@tsv` or utilize `join/1` to output in the format of your choice.

```
jq -r '.[] | [.location] + (.services[] | [.name, .version]) | @tsv' input.json
```